# Managing browser permissions with Laravel Dusk

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

Total Laravel Dusk noob here (started using it today). I wanted to test a "copy link" on the Web app I'm working on and I ran into browser permissions issues when trying to access the clipboard content while testing. Of course, that default behavior makes sense, because Google Chrome prompts the user and ask for permission to access the clipboard. However, I haven't found a way to tell Dusk to enable specific permissions. I found the following Cypress example that is probably the appropriate way of doing it, but I don't know if there's a Dusk equivalent.

```js
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
  command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
  params: {
    permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
    origin: window.location.origin,
  },
}))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this function to your DuskTestCase class.

```php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDevToolsDriver;
//

protected function grantPermission(Browser $browser, $permissions)
{
    try {
        $driver = $browser->driver;
        $devtools = new ChromeDevToolsDriver($driver);

        $result = $devtools->execute('Browser.grantPermissions', [
            "permissions" => $permissions,
        ]);

        return $result;
    } catch (\Exception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it globally in a real test case like this

```php
public function testClipboard()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
       $this->grantPermission($browser, ["clipboardReadWrite", "clipboardSanitizedWrite"]);

       // Your test flow and assertion
    });
}
```

Hope my answer can help.